# how to pass parameter to a function when it's called inside another function in shell

Tags: bash, shell, ubuntu, sh

I have shell script with 2 functions like below:

```
lines(){
    while IFS="" read -l
    do
        line=$(wc -l < "something.txt")
        if [ "$line" = "$1" ] ; then
           do something...
           echo "lines are: "$l""       
        else

         #calling files function here
         files
         do something...
         fi
    done<something.txt
}
files(){
    do something....
    echo "something...\n""$(lines "$1")"
}
####Main
case "$1" in
   lines)
        shift
        lines "$1"
        ;;
   *)
esac
```

I am trying to run the script like this on an ubuntu machine:

```
 sh files.sh line 3
```

I have some if operations where 
In `files` I am trying to call `lines` function. When it's called and goes back to perform the actions in `lines()`, the argument I am trying to pass from the command line `3` i.e., `"$1"` is being passed as `null (empty)`
Can someone help me how I can have `lines` function read the parameter I am passing from the command line
Thanks

Comment: Two options: (1) Assign it to a named variable and refer to that name. (2) Pass all arguments through with "$@".

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Comment: @Barmar, ...the OP's function named `files` is called with no arguments, but refers to `$1`, so there *is* a clear issue in the code given in the question.

Comment: I thought he was talking about referring to `$1` in `lines()`.

Comment: @user6348718, ...btw, `sh` and `bash` are two different shells, and the answer to this question will be different between them (as `sh` doesn't have array support, this is harder to implement in a clean manner that doesn't depend on modified calling conventions). I'm *assuming* that because you tagged for both, you'll accept an answer for either.

Comment: I have func1 performing all the operations and requires me to pass a parameter $1, when func2 is called in func1 then, -> func2 should do something and call func1 by taking the same $1 and doing all the operations in func1

Comment: What is `read -l` supposed to do? That's not a valid option, and you're missing the variable to read into. Why do you get the size of `something.txt` every time through the loop, it's not going to change.

Comment: Why don't you do `files "$1"`?

Comment: @Barmar that's some dummy code, I am actually performing some arthimetic operations in func1 i.e., `lines` w.r.t to `$1`

Comment: What is `$(name "$1")`? There's no `name` function in your script.

Comment: Following the [mcve] guidelines -- testing that the code in the question *actually runs* (and causes a specific, explicitly-described problem), and providing both its current output and its desired output -- would avoid all this quibbling, as an answer describing a change causing the code to generate the desired output would be provably, irrefutably correct. (Also note that an essential element of that definition is that code should be the *shortest possible thing* that reproduces a given problem, with any unnecessary elements removed).

Comment: If it's just dummy code, just remove it, since it's not relevant at all to the problem with `$1`.

Comment: @Barmar I updated it, it's not `names` , it's `lines` that's getting called in `files`

Comment: `do something...` can't be part of a MCVE. A MCVE should be *verifiable* -- that is, someone who isn't you should be able to run it and get your same problem (and your problem isn't a syntax error, which the code with `do something...` creates).

Comment: So `lines` calls `files` and `files` calls `lines`, don't you get infinite recursion?

Comment: @Barmar No, I don't. I have something that's gets updated after a few mins. So by the time when `files` calls `lines`, I have the updated something that I am checking in `lines` and it thus exits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Positional parameters are local to each function. So `files` can't access the `$1` variable of `lines` by itself, you need to pass it explicitly:

```
files "$1"
```

Answer (score 2):

The easy thing to do is to just create a global array variable that preserves your original command-line arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
[ "$BASH_VERSION" ] || { echo "ERROR: This script requires bash" >&2; exit 1; }

args=( "$0" "$@" )

func1() { func2 "local-arg1" "local-arg2"; }
func2() { echo "Function argument 1 is $1; original argument 2 is ${args[2]}"; }
func1
```

...will, if called as `./scriptname global-arg1 global-arg2`, emit as output:

```
Function argument 1 is local-arg1; original argument 2 is global-arg2
```

Comment: I have func1 performing all the operations and requires me to pass a parameter $1, when func2 is called in func1 then, -> func2 should do something and call func1 by taking the same $1 and doing all the operations in func1

Comment: @user6348718, ...which has what to do with anything?

Comment: @user6348718, ...that is to say, for purposes of this answer, the calling convention between func1 and func2 *doesn't matter*, because global arguments are out-of-band from function-local ones. Modifications to those calling conventions don't change the answer's applicability at all.